# Unable to resolve action actions/powershell-script, repository not found

Tags: powershell, .net-core, github-actions

I keep getting this error when deploying: Unable to resolve action actions/powershell-script, repository not found

This is my file:

```
name: Deploy .NET API

on:
    push:
      branches:
        - master
    workflow_dispatch:


jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '7.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Build API
        run: dotnet build

      - name: Publish API
        run: dotnet publish

  deploy:
    needs: build

    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Download build artifacts
        uses: actions/github-script@v6

        with:
          script: |
            github.actions.downloadArtifact('build', {directory: './artifacts'})



        - name: PowerShell script
        uses: Amadevus/pwsh-script@v2.0.3
    

        with:
          script: |
            $ServerHost = ${{ secrets.REMOTE_SERVER_HOST }}
            $ServerUsername = ${{ secrets.REMOTE_SERVER_USERNAME }}
            $ServerPassword = ${{ secrets.REMOTE_SERVER_PASSWORD }}

            # Create a temporary directory
            $TempDir = New-TemporaryItem

            # Copy the build artifacts to the temporary directory
            Copy-Item -Path .\artifacts\* -Destination $TempDir

            # Create a PowerShell script to deploy the API to the remote server
            $DeployScript = New-Item -ItemType File -Path $TempDir\Deploy.ps1 -Force

            Add-Content -Path $DeployScript -Value "@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File $TempDir\Publish.ps1"

            # Copy the PowerShell script to the remote server
            Copy-Item -Path $DeployScript -Destination \\$ServerHost\C$\Temp

            # Create a PowerShell session on the remote server
            $RemoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ServerHost -Credential (New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($ServerUsername, $ServerPassword))

            # Execute the PowerShell script on the remote server to deploy the API
            Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession -ScriptBlock { Import-Module PSReadLine; . \\$ServerHost\C$\Temp\Deploy.ps1 }

            # Close the PowerShell session on the remote server
            Remove-PSSession $RemoteSession

            # Remove the temporary directory
            Remove-Item -Path $TempDir -Force
```

I'm expecting to deploy my .NET API on to a remote Windows server through GitHub Actions

Comment: That indeed [does not exist](https://github.com/actions/powershell-script)

Comment: That action doesn't seem to be referenced in the workflow you're showing?

Comment: Please add the complete error log including its job and step as well. You are using `Amadevus/pwsh-script` and not `actions/powershell-script` so it's not clear where that error is coming from.